# Display and use time values on Highcharts

Tags: time, highcharts, yaxis

I'm quite new to Highcharts and the documentation is pretty huge for me to solve my little big problem.

I'm working on app for runners and want to display running pace on chart in minutes:seconds by kilometer or mile, in format like 05:30, which means pace 5 minutes and 30 seconds pre kilometer or mile.

My current (and not working) code is here:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
  categories:  ['03:30','04:00','04:30','05:00','05:30','06:00','06:30','07:00','07:30','08:00','08:30'],
      labels: { format: '{value:%H:%M}'}
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['2018-01-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-10-01']
},
series: [{
    data: ['05:00', '06:00' , '06:30'],
    dataLabels: { format: '{value:%H:%M}'}
}],
legend: {layout: 'vertical',align: 'right',verticalAlign: 'middle'},
plotOptions: {series: {label: {connectorAllowed: false},pointStart: 0}},
responsive: {rules: [{condition: {maxWidth: 1000},chartOptions: {legend: {layout: 'horizontal',align: 'center',verticalAlign: 'bottom'}}}]}
});
```

Currently the line in chart is not appearing. Can anybody repair my code to work correctly?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data needs to be numbers, not string values. If you look in console, you will most likely have [Error 14](http://highcharts.com/errors/14) telling you this.

Changing your data to milliseconds (the format needed for highcharts to understand time) will work, like this:

```
data: [5 * 3600 * 1000, 06 * 3600 * 1000, 6.5 * 3600 * 1000],
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/55bk99ke/2/

If you want to fix the tooltip in the above example, you just need to format it the same way you format the yAxis labels. Like this:

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormat: '{point.y:%H:%M}'
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/55bk99ke/5/

Comment: Great, this works. One more thing - how to display (on hover) "readable" value like 5:00, 6:00 or 6:30?

Comment: @mesnicka Added a second example to show you how to do that.